# Getting an Git related Error when trying to build or serve with new theme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, jekyll

**Description:**

For some reason, I can't build or serve my jekyll site without "configuring a repo name". I have no clue why there would be a repo name needed for a local build or how to add the repo name.

This is the first time this happened. I tried to migrate the default site from "minima" to "jekyll-theme-primer". When I fired it up in minima it outputted me the default side. I migrated the default post, index.md and about to layout default. It does not fire up and throws me this error. Can somebody specify how to move on from here?

**Input:**

```
jekyll -v: jekyll 3.7.2
```

**Expected behaviour:**

```
Tobiass-MBP:tobi.codes Tobias$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /Users/Tobias/Jekyll Blog/tobi.codes/_config.yml
            Source:  /Users/Tobias/Jekyll Blog/tobi.codes/
       Destination:  /Users/Tobias/Jekyll Blog/tobi.codes/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.62 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for ' /Users/Tobias/Jekyll Blog/tobi.codes/'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

**Actual behaviour:**

```
Tobiass-MBP:tobi.codes Tobias$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /Users/Tobias/Jekyll Blog/tobi.codes/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/Tobias/Jekyll Blog/tobi.codes
       Destination: /Users/Tobias/Jekyll Blog/tobi.codes/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
  Liquid Exception: No repo name found. Specify using PAGES_REPO_NWO environment variables, 'repository' in your configuration, or set up an 'origin' git remote pointing to your github.com repository. in /_layouts/default.html
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    No repo name found. Specify using PAGES_REPO_NWO environment variables, 'repository' in your configuration, or set up an 'origin' git remote pointing to your github.com repository.
```

Comment: The error message is giving you very good instructions. `Specify using PAGES_REPO_NWO environment variables, 'repository' in your configuration, or set up an 'origin' git remote pointing to your github.com repository.` It seems your new theme makes use of the repository URL, and can't find it.

Comment: I'm trying to test the site locally and don't want to deploy. Is is mandatory to add a repo in order to get the site to run on http://127.0.0.1:4000/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jekyll-theme-primer theme uses [jekyll-github-metadata plugin](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata).

The error happens in [default layout](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer/blob/master/_layouts/default.html#L19) when `site.github` is called, because you did not configure it.

You can get rid of this error by copying this file in ***_layouts/default.html*** and removing lines 19 to 23.

```
{% if site.github.private != true and site.github.license %}
<div class="footer border-top border-gray-light mt-5 pt-3 text-right text-gray">
  This site is open source. {% github_edit_link "Improve this page" %}.
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Where do I find said _layouts/default.html? I searched for it, but it's not in the pagefolder or in the theme folder

Comment: Make a **_layouts** folder with a **default.html** file and copy this https://github.com/pages-themes/primer/blob/master/_layouts/default.html into it.

Comment: It works now, thank you - but I'm not sure what it is I deleted. Can you specify WHY it works?

Comment: Can you help me improve the question? I got downvoted pretty bad for another question, in need to improve the existing ones.